# getting results of custom action in rails with angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using rails 3.2 with angularjs, and I'm trying to understand how to use angular's $resource.

I would like resource to return the results from a non-default action (so not get, save, query, remove, and delete)

So in my Posts controller I have

```
def home
  @recent_posts = Post.recent_posts
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
  end
end
```

And then in my js file I have

```
app.factory "Post", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/post/:id/:action", {id: "@id"}, {home: {method: "GET", isArray: true}})
]

@HomeCtrl = ["$scope", "Post", ($scope, Post) ->
  $scope.recent_posts = Post.home()
]
```

In my view if I try and do something like `ng-repeat="post in recent_posts"`, it's not returning anything.

Comment: `$scope.recent_posts = Post.home({action:'home', function(response){console.log(response) }, function(response){console.log(response)} })`. Please have these callbacks registered and check whats coming in the response. The first function is the success callback, the second one is the error callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, they helped me get to what eventually worked. I just changed the Home Controller like so:

```
@HomeCtrl = ["$scope", "Post", ($scope, Post) ->
  $scope.recent_posts = Post.home({action:'home'});
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the `action` parameter:

```
app.factory "Post", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource "/post/:id/:action",
    id: "@id"
  ,
    home:
      method: "GET"
      params:
        action: "home"

      isArray: true

]
```